# Add Scroll bar in JEditorPane, setLayout null

Tags: java, jeditorpane

I can't add scroll bar on EditorPane.

```
private JEditorPane editorPane;
private JScrollPane scrollpane;
```

Container :

```
Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(null);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

    editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setBounds(0, 54, 434, 208);

    scrollpane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
    scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 110));

    c.add(scrollpane);
```

..
..
Nothing added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're shooting yourself in the foot here:

```
editorPane.setBounds(0, 54, 434, 208);
```

By setting the editorPane's absolute size, you prevent it from expanding when it needs to do so, preventing the JScrollBars from having to show.

Solution: don't do this. And yeah, avoid using null layouts. They'll bite you, as you're finding out. Set the width using CSS

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> getContentPane().setLayout(null);
> ```

This means *"I give a damn on the help of others because I know better that anyone else how to layout a GUI!"*

So this is where you are.

I'd recomment to go through the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and learn how to build GUIs using LayoutManagers.